# E/OMXNodeInstance: setConfig(a0:google.raw.decoder, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)

Tags: android, logging

I have a problem with my app. It doesn't crash and everything works fine when testing the app. But the following message log keeps showing when I start recording audio:

```
E/OMXNodeInstance: setConfig(a0:google.raw.decoder, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: i just love how noone knows. :(

Answer (score 0):

Happening for when I am using media codec to encode a video in DEBUG mode on Xiaomi POCO phone only. The bug is gone in release mode.  Make sure you don't create multiple instance of MediaCodec. this seems to be a device specific issue in debug mode

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and had audio issues, but another error was the cause:

`AudioFlinger: no more track names available`

I fixed this by:

1. Converting my audio file from .wav to .mp3, one of the [supported formats](https://developer.android.com/media/platform/supported-formats#audio-formats)
2. Restarting my emulator

When I had the error, I was also debugging a `MediaPlayer.release()` issue, so I suspect my device had some buggy state, which was fixed by restarting the emulator.